# how to find index/position of an element in set in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to find index of an element in a set. 
For example, if s={2,5,8,9,12} 
index/position of 8 is 2, index/position of 12 is 4.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By "set", do you mean `std::set`?

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What have you tried? @user463035818: `set` is an ordered collection. | http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @VittorioRomeo yeah sorry, i removed my misleading comment. I wanted to say: if you care about the index of elements then quite likely `set` is the wrong container ;)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I know set is an ordered collection. I want to find specific element's index.

Answer (score 2):

While [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is indeed ordered, the keys in the set have no indexes. The key is its own index, in a way.

You can [get an iterator to a specific key](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) and get its [distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) from  [the first key in the set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin), but that distance is not an index.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` doesn't have a `operator[]`, and you're not supposed to use it by passing an index.

Instead, to find an element use `std::set::find` to get an iterator to the object you're looking for, you can read more about it here.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find